# Placeholder's text disappears after running this js code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a problem while using this (enter multiple emails in an input) that I got from here https://github.com/pierresh/multiple-emails.js/tree/master

the problem is that when I enter a placeholder text onto the input field, it appears for a few second then disappears, I have tried finding out the problems in the js and css file but I still failed to find what causes the placeholder text to disappear.

I tried added this code at a lot of place but the text still disappears

```
$("#emailInviteList").attr("placeholder", "Friend's email").blur();
```

this is the multiple-emails.js

```
(function( $ ){

$.fn.multiple_emails = function(options) {

    // Default options
    var defaults = {
        checkDupEmail: true,
        theme: "Bootstrap",
        position: "top"
    };

    // Merge send options with defaults
    var settings = $.extend( {}, defaults, options );

    var deleteIconHTML = "";
    if (settings.theme.toLowerCase() == "Bootstrap".toLowerCase())
    {
        deleteIconHTML = '<a href="#" class="multiple_emails-close" title="Remove"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>';
    }
    else if (settings.theme.toLowerCase() == "SemanticUI".toLowerCase() || settings.theme.toLowerCase() == "Semantic-UI".toLowerCase() || settings.theme.toLowerCase() == "Semantic UI".toLowerCase()) {
        deleteIconHTML = '<a href="#" class="multiple_emails-close" title="Remove"><i class="remove icon"></i></a>';
    }
    else if (settings.theme.toLowerCase() == "Basic".toLowerCase()) {
        //Default which you should use if you don't use Bootstrap, SemanticUI, or other CSS frameworks
        deleteIconHTML = '<a href="#" class="multiple_emails-close" title="Remove"><i class="basicdeleteicon">Remove</i></a>';
    }

    return this.each(function() {
        //$orig refers to the input HTML node
        var $orig = $(this);
        var $list = $('<ul class="multiple_emails-ul" />'); // create html elements - list of email addresses as unordered list

        if ($(this).val() != '' && IsJsonString($(this).val())) {
            $.each(jQuery.parseJSON($(this).val()), function( index, val ) {
                $list.append($('<li class="multiple_emails-email"><span class="email_name" data-email="' + val.toLowerCase() + '">' + val + '</span></li>')
                  .prepend($(deleteIconHTML)
                       .click(function(e) { $(this).parent().remove(); refresh_emails(); e.preventDefault(); })
                  )
                );
            });
        }

        var $input = $('<input type="text" class="multiple_emails-input text-left" />').on('keyup', function(e) { // input
            $(this).removeClass('multiple_emails-error');
            var input_length = $(this).val().length;

            var keynum;
            if(window.event){ // IE
                keynum = e.keyCode;
            }
            else if(e.which){ // Netscape/Firefox/Opera
                keynum = e.which;
            }

            //if(event.which == 8 && input_length == 0) { $list.find('li').last().remove(); } //Removes last item on backspace with no input

            // Supported key press is tab, enter, space or comma, there is no support for semi-colon since the keyCode differs in various browsers
            if(keynum == 9 || keynum == 32 || keynum == 188) {
                display_email($(this), settings.checkDupEmail);
            }
            else if (keynum == 13) {
                display_email($(this), settings.checkDupEmail);
                //Prevents enter key default
                //This is to prevent the form from submitting with  the submit button
                //when you press enter in the email textbox
                e.preventDefault();
            }

        }).on('blur', function(event){
            if ($(this).val() != '') { display_email($(this), settings.checkDupEmail); }
        });

        var $container = $('<div class="multiple_emails-container" />').click(function() { $input.focus(); } ); // container div

        // insert elements into DOM
        if (settings.position.toLowerCase() === "top")
            $container.append($list).append($input).insertAfter($(this));
        else
            $container.append($input).append($list).insertBefore($(this));

        /*
        t is the text input device.
        Value of the input could be a long line of copy-pasted emails, not just a single email.
        As such, the string is tokenized, with each token validated individually.

        If the dupEmailCheck variable is set to true, scans for duplicate emails, and invalidates input if found.
        Otherwise allows emails to have duplicated values if false.
        */
        function display_email(t, dupEmailCheck) {

            //Remove space, comma and semi-colon from beginning and end of string
            //Does not remove inside the string as the email will need to be tokenized using space, comma and semi-colon
            var arr = t.val().trim().replace(/^,|,$/g , '').replace(/^;|;$/g , '');
            //Remove the double quote
            arr = arr.replace(/"/g,"");
            //Split the string into an array, with the space, comma, and semi-colon as the separator
            arr = arr.split(/[\s,;]+/);

            var errorEmails = new Array(); //New array to contain the errors

            var pattern = new RegExp(/^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i);

            for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                //Check if the email is already added, only if dupEmailCheck is set to true
                if ( dupEmailCheck === true && $orig.val().indexOf(arr[i]) != -1 ) {
                    if (arr[i] && arr[i].length > 0) {
                        new function () {
                            var existingElement = $list.find('.email_name[data-email=' + arr[i].toLowerCase().replace('.', '\\.').replace('@', '\\@') + ']');
                            existingElement.css('font-weight', 'bold');
                            setTimeout(function() { existingElement.css('font-weight', ''); }, 1500);
                        }(); // Use a IIFE function to create a new scope so existingElement won't be overriden
                    }
                }
                else if (pattern.test(arr[i]) == true) {
                    $list.append($('<li class="multiple_emails-email"><span class="email_name" data-email="' + arr[i].toLowerCase() + '">' + arr[i] + '</span></li>')
                          .prepend($(deleteIconHTML)
                               .click(function(e) { $(this).parent().remove(); refresh_emails(); e.preventDefault(); })
                          )
                    );
                }
                else
                    errorEmails.push(arr[i]);
            }
            // If erroneous emails found, or if duplicate email found
            if(errorEmails.length > 0)
                t.val(errorEmails.join("; ")).addClass('multiple_emails-error');
            else
                t.val("");
            refresh_emails ();
        }

        function refresh_emails () {
            var emails = new Array();
            var container = $orig.siblings('.multiple_emails-container');
            container.find('.multiple_emails-email span.email_name').each(function() { emails.push($(this).html()); });
            $orig.val(JSON.stringify(emails)).trigger('change');
        }

        function IsJsonString(str) {
            try { JSON.parse(str); }
            catch (e) { return false; }
            return true;
        }

        return $(this).hide();

    });

};

})(jQuery);
```

this is the multiple-emails.css

```
            .multiple_emails-container {
                border:1px #ccc solid;
                border-radius: 4px;
                box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
                padding:0; margin: 0; cursor:text; width:100%;
                padding-top: 5px;
                background-color: white;
            }

            .multiple_emails-container input {
                clear:both;
                width:100%;
                height: 30px;
                text-align: center;
                border:0;
                outline: none;
                margin-bottom:3px;
                padding-left: 5px;
                box-sizing: border-box;
            }

            .multiple_emails-container input{
                border: 0 !important;
            }

            .multiple_emails-container input.multiple_emails-error {
                box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 6px red !important;
                outline: thin auto red !important;
            }

            .multiple_emails-container ul {
                list-style-type:none;
                padding-left: 0;
            }

            .multiple_emails-email {
                margin: 3px 5px 3px 5px;
                padding: 3px 5px 3px 5px;
                border:1px #BBD8FB solid;
                border-radius: 3px;
                background: #F3F7FD;
            }

            .multiple_emails-close {
                float:left;
                margin:0 3px;
            }
```

this is part of my code in the html file

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#emailInviteList').multiple_emails({position: "bottom"});
    });
</script>

<div class='form-group'>
    <input type='email' id='emailInviteList' name='emailInviteList' class="form-control" placeholder="Friend's Email">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Script is creating another textfield which does not have `placeholder` attribute, below is updated snippet I have just added `placeholder="Friend\'s Email"` in input `var $input`.

```js
(function( $ ){

$.fn.multiple_emails = function(options) {

    // Default options
    var defaults = {
        checkDupEmail: true,
        theme: "Bootstrap",
        position: "top"
    };

    // Merge send options with defaults
    var settings = $.extend( {}, defaults, options );

    var deleteIconHTML = "";
    if (settings.theme.toLowerCase() == "Bootstrap".toLowerCase())
    {
        deleteIconHTML = '<a href="#" class="multiple_emails-close" title="Remove"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>';
    }
    else if (settings.theme.toLowerCase() == "SemanticUI".toLowerCase() || settings.theme.toLowerCase() == "Semantic-UI".toLowerCase() || settings.theme.toLowerCase() == "Semantic UI".toLowerCase()) {
        deleteIconHTML = '<a href="#" class="multiple_emails-close" title="Remove"><i class="remove icon"></i></a>';
    }
    else if (settings.theme.toLowerCase() == "Basic".toLowerCase()) {
        //Default which you should use if you don't use Bootstrap, SemanticUI, or other CSS frameworks
        deleteIconHTML = '<a href="#" class="multiple_emails-close" title="Remove"><i class="basicdeleteicon">Remove</i></a>';
    }

    return this.each(function() {
        //$orig refers to the input HTML node
        var $orig = $(this);
        var $list = $('<ul class="multiple_emails-ul" />'); // create html elements - list of email addresses as unordered list

        if ($(this).val() != '' && IsJsonString($(this).val())) {
            $.each(jQuery.parseJSON($(this).val()), function( index, val ) {
                $list.append($('<li class="multiple_emails-email"><span class="email_name" data-email="' + val.toLowerCase() + '">' + val + '</span></li>')
                  .prepend($(deleteIconHTML)
                       .click(function(e) { $(this).parent().remove(); refresh_emails(); e.preventDefault(); })
                  )
                );
            });
        }

        var $input = $('<input type="text" class="multiple_emails-input text-left" placeholder="Friend\'s Email" />').on('keyup', function(e) { // input
            $(this).removeClass('multiple_emails-error');
            var input_length = $(this).val().length;

            var keynum;
            if(window.event){ // IE
                keynum = e.keyCode;
            }
            else if(e.which){ // Netscape/Firefox/Opera
                keynum = e.which;
            }

            //if(event.which == 8 && input_length == 0) { $list.find('li').last().remove(); } //Removes last item on backspace with no input

            // Supported key press is tab, enter, space or comma, there is no support for semi-colon since the keyCode differs in various browsers
            if(keynum == 9 || keynum == 32 || keynum == 188) {
                display_email($(this), settings.checkDupEmail);
            }
            else if (keynum == 13) {
                display_email($(this), settings.checkDupEmail);
                //Prevents enter key default
                //This is to prevent the form from submitting with  the submit button
                //when you press enter in the email textbox
                e.preventDefault();
            }

        }).on('blur', function(event){
            if ($(this).val() != '') { display_email($(this), settings.checkDupEmail); }
        });

        var $container = $('<div class="multiple_emails-container" />').click(function() { $input.focus(); } ); // container div

        // insert elements into DOM
        if (settings.position.toLowerCase() === "top")
            $container.append($list).append($input).insertAfter($(this));
        else
            $container.append($input).append($list).insertBefore($(this));

        /*
        t is the text input device.
        Value of the input could be a long line of copy-pasted emails, not just a single email.
        As such, the string is tokenized, with each token validated individually.

        If the dupEmailCheck variable is set to true, scans for duplicate emails, and invalidates input if found.
        Otherwise allows emails to have duplicated values if false.
        */
        function display_email(t, dupEmailCheck) {

            //Remove space, comma and semi-colon from beginning and end of string
            //Does not remove inside the string as the email will need to be tokenized using space, comma and semi-colon
            var arr = t.val().trim().replace(/^,|,$/g , '').replace(/^;|;$/g , '');
            //Remove the double quote
            arr = arr.replace(/"/g,"");
            //Split the string into an array, with the space, comma, and semi-colon as the separator
            arr = arr.split(/[\s,;]+/);

            var errorEmails = new Array(); //New array to contain the errors

            var pattern = new RegExp(/^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i);

            for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                //Check if the email is already added, only if dupEmailCheck is set to true
                if ( dupEmailCheck === true && $orig.val().indexOf(arr[i]) != -1 ) {
                    if (arr[i] && arr[i].length > 0) {
                        new function () {
                            var existingElement = $list.find('.email_name[data-email=' + arr[i].toLowerCase().replace('.', '\\.').replace('@', '\\@') + ']');
                            existingElement.css('font-weight', 'bold');
                            setTimeout(function() { existingElement.css('font-weight', ''); }, 1500);
                        }(); // Use a IIFE function to create a new scope so existingElement won't be overriden
                    }
                }
                else if (pattern.test(arr[i]) == true) {
                    $list.append($('<li class="multiple_emails-email"><span class="email_name" data-email="' + arr[i].toLowerCase() + '">' + arr[i] + '</span></li>')
                          .prepend($(deleteIconHTML)
                               .click(function(e) { $(this).parent().remove(); refresh_emails(); e.preventDefault(); })
                          )
                    );
                }
                else
                    errorEmails.push(arr[i]);
            }
            // If erroneous emails found, or if duplicate email found
            if(errorEmails.length > 0)
                t.val(errorEmails.join("; ")).addClass('multiple_emails-error');
            else
                t.val("");
            refresh_emails ();
        }

        function refresh_emails () {
            var emails = new Array();
            var container = $orig.siblings('.multiple_emails-container');
            container.find('.multiple_emails-email span.email_name').each(function() { emails.push($(this).html()); });
            $orig.val(JSON.stringify(emails)).trigger('change');
        }

        function IsJsonString(str) {
            try { JSON.parse(str); }
            catch (e) { return false; }
            return true;
        }

        return $(this).hide();

    });

};

})(jQuery);
```

```css
            .multiple_emails-container {
                border:1px #ccc solid;
                border-radius: 4px;
                box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
                padding:0; margin: 0; cursor:text; width:100%;
                padding-top: 5px;
                background-color: white;
            }

            .multiple_emails-container input {
                clear:both;
                width:100%;
                height: 30px;
                text-align: center;
                border:0;
                outline: none;
                margin-bottom:3px;
                padding-left: 5px;
                box-sizing: border-box;
            }

            .multiple_emails-container input{
                border: 0 !important;
            }

            .multiple_emails-container input.multiple_emails-error {
                box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 6px red !important;
                outline: thin auto red !important;
            }

            .multiple_emails-container ul {
                list-style-type:none;
                padding-left: 0;
            }

            .multiple_emails-email {
                margin: 3px 5px 3px 5px;
                padding: 3px 5px 3px 5px;
                border:1px #BBD8FB solid;
                border-radius: 3px;
                background: #F3F7FD;
            }

            .multiple_emails-close {
                float:left;
                margin:0 3px;
            }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
       $('#emailInviteList').multiple_emails({position: "bottom"});
    });
</script>

<div class='form-group'>
    <input type='email' id='emailInviteList' name='emailInviteList' class="form-control" placeholder="Friend's Email">
</div>
```